# Analysing function at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity, rolles-theorem

I am solving real analysis notes of my friend where i am having doubt in the below problem.

> Show that if $x>0$, $\log(1+x)>\frac x{1+x}$ and hence prove that $x^{-1}\log(1+x)$ decreases monotonically as $x$ increases from $0$ to $\infty$.

> **Solution**: Let $f(x)=\log(1+x)-\frac x{1+x}$, then
> $$f'(x)=\frac1{1+x}-\frac{(1+x)\cdot1-x}{(1+x)^2}=\frac x{(1+x)^2}>0\ (\because x>0)$$
> $$\therefore x>0\implies f'(x)>0$$
> i.e $f$ is an increasing when $x>0$ and $f(x)>f(0)$.

In the text, the author has directly stated that $f(x) > f(0)$ even though  $f'(x) > 0 $ only when $x>0$. My understanding of the problem is as follows.

Technically speaking , given that $f'(x) > 0$ when $x > 0$ , $\implies$ $f'(x) > f(0^+)$ . Since the function is continuous at $x = 0$ , hence,  $\;f(0^+) = f(0) $ which leads to $f(x) > f(0)$.

My questions to the community are as follows :-

1. Does my reasoning holds good ?
2. If someone can explain / reason what is happening to the function $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ and you are abusing notation by writing something like $f(0^+) < f(x)$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi what about reasoning given in the text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is not correct. Argue as follows:  Suppose $x<y$. The only case when we have difficulty in showing that $f(x) <f(y)$ is when $x=0$. In this case prove by contradiction. Suppose $f(0)(=f(x))\geq f(y)$. We have $f(\frac  1 n) < f(\frac  y 2) $ for all $n$ such that $\frac 1 n <\frac y 2$.   Letting $n \to \infty$ and using continuity at $0$ we get $f(0) \leq f(\frac y 2) <f(y)$. [Note that $<$ becomes $\leq $ in the limit. **This is important**]. We have now arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for answering my doubt. If you could elaborate a little bit in this line $f(\frac  1 n) < f(\frac  y 2)$ for all  such that $\frac 1 n <\frac y 2$ as $n \to \infty$ $\implies$ $f(0) \leq f(\frac y 2) $, particularly the part on $\leq$ and how the equality came using definitions of continuity .

Comment: Just take limit on both sides as $n \to \infty$. But strict inequality does not remain after taking a limit For example, $\frac 1 n >0$ for all $n$. But when you take limit you won't get $0 >0$. You only get $0 \geq 0$. @HarshVardhanSingh

Comment: Sir , what are the checkpoints in taking limits in an inequality ? if the two functions given across the inequality are continuous in the domain , can we always take the limit , taking into account that after taking the limit , we should consider the equality sign? Is there a general rule to that , or we need to analyse what is happening with the function every now and then.

Comment: If $a_n <b_n$ for all $n$ and if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are convergent with limits $a$ and $b$ then $a \leq b$. [You can prove this using definition of limit]. I am just taking $a_n=f(\frac 1 n)$ which has  the limit $f(0)$ because of continuity of $f$ and $b_n=f(\frac y 2)$ for all $n$. @HarshVardhanSingh

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy ,this was really helpful . I forgot to use this definition . Thanks.